# sync button state in realtime using APIs in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have two APIs one is Post API Which I linked to my Toggle button, whenever button is clicked it sends 1 or 0 value to Post API and I have other GET API from where I'm getting the state of value which I'm using to the same button to check weather it is 0 or 1.
The problem is my code works but it can't get sync because when I click button it updates state value through post API but previous GET Request Makes it again on previous state. so on render button flickers a couple of times and then get settled. Code is given below. Any solution will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
P.S. on componentDidMount() I'm Calling the GET Request and handleChange is linked to the button

```
class Test extends React. Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this. State = {
                checked: false,
                value:bool,
                
            }
            
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.intervalId = setInterval(()=> this.loadData(), 1000);
        this.loadData();
         
      }
  
      componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.intervalId);
      }
  
      async loadData() {
        const headers = { 
            'api-key': 'key',
            
        };
        try {
        const response = await fetch('url', { headers })
        const json =  await response.json();
        const valueUp = json.data ;
        
        
        
        if( valueUp ===1 ) {
            this.setState({value: valueUp, checked: true})
        }
        else if (valueUp === 0) {
                this.setState({value: valueUp, checked: false})
        }

        }
        catch (err){ console.log(err);}
    
        
    }


    handleChange() {
        if (this.state.value === 0) {
        this.setState({ value:1, checked: true }, () => {
            this.afterSetStateFinished();
            
        })
        
        }
        else if (this.state.value === 1) {
            this.setState({ value:0, checked: false }, () => {

                this.afterSetStateFinished();
            })
        }
        
        
        
        
    };
        
    afterSetStateFinished(){
        const article = { 
            "body": this.state.value
             }
        const headers = { 
            'api-key': 'key',
            
        };
         axios.post('url', article, { headers })
            .then(function(response) {console.log(response);
            })
    }
```

Comment: maybe the get is being cached by the browser - maybe send headers to avoid that in the response? Not sure of your backend, so can't tell you what to do with that

Comment: You're calling `loadData` once per second, updating the state each time. That is not necessary unless multiple instances of your app are changing the server state. And if they do, polling the server once per second is not an ideal way; I'd use sockets instead.

Comment: headers is necessary because API don't response without authorization.

Comment: I'm calling `loadData` once per second because the state can be changed in backend but i don't have a way to check weather it changed or not that's why i keep checking the state once per second